# In a create view, insert data at the same time to two different table in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an ASP.NET MVC project and I'm having trouble to make the create view work: it doesn't save data into two tables. I'm creating a client with name, email, address, zipcode + city.

These are my two tables:

`Clients` table:

```
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MailID { get; set; }
    public virtual PostOffices PostOffices { get; set; }
```

And then I have `PostOffices` table:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PostOffices()
    {
        this.Clients = new HashSet<Clients>();
    }

    public int MailID { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
```

I have written a controller looking like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ClientID,Name,Email,Address,MailID")] Clients clients)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Asiakkaat.Add(asiakkaat);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(asiakkaat);
    }
```

In the view it shows everything and lets me enter data into all of the input boxes, but it only saves data to the `Clients` table like name, email, address, but it doesn't save anything into the `PostOffices` table (meaning zipcode and city).

Is there something wrong with my controller? Or should I somehow add into a client class a zipcode + city, and not the MailID? I can't get it to work.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove [Bind] and never use this attribute in the future

```
 public ActionResult Create( Clients clients)
```

Comment: Nice it worked!! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You are welcome again!